# Sharepoint Date Only Column

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

Is there anyway I can display a sharepoint column just date only, I can see when I add new column only date and time format option is there.

```
$fieldXml = "<Field Type='DateTime' DisplayName='Date Created0' Name='DocCreated' Format='DateOnly' />"
Add-PnPFieldFromXml -List $ListName -FieldXml $fieldXml
```

This works , but I have trouble in displaying this field in search page, Any suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: You have a DateTime object and have two choices.  1) Use Date property which truncates the DateTime to midnight at the beginning of the day 2) Use ToString('MM_dd_yyyy') method which converts to a string

Comment: Thank You @jdweng , I went for second option and it works